# spring security login logout uris

Tags: spring, spring-security

recently I'm working on a J2EE Web App we're introducing Spring Security,
I have some question about, but one major is:

My application hasn't a login page and/or log out ones, so the login/logout is a small box in the main page, so when a user try to login, even logout, he/she will be redirected to same "/" page. How can achieve this in my `<http><form-login>` configuration?

Thanks
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following configuration

```
<form-login login-page="/" default-target-url="/" authentication-failure-url="/?error=true">
```